# How to resolve the issues with Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have installed Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0.RELEASE, Its very slow. I am working on grails project now. Sometimes it does not even respond and for every save it takes time to build and its slow.

I changed the values as below

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Even after increasing the memory also, Its slow

I get messages as below.(for better view of image, please open it new tab)
[image]

```
My Laptop RAM size: 3.00 GB
```

How to make STS work really fast.

Comment: have you tried `GGTS`? it should be more appropriate for groovy/grails projects. Btw 3 GB RAM is too few. My laptop has 8 GB and i7 + SSD to run GGTS/STS fluently

Comment: Even it is slow, I tried that

Comment: @injecteer GGTS is just a variant of STS with the Grails plugin already installed.

Comment: A time consuming is the automatic build, have you tried disabling this option?

Comment: its much better now after disabling the "Automatic Build" option